# How can we do get operation without using primary(instead use some other field )in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

```
exports.findManager = function (req, res) {
// Find all registration details of a user
Registrations.
    find({ requester_manager_id: req.params.managerId }).

    exec(function (err, registrationdetails) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error("Error while retrieving registration details: " + err)
            res.status(500).send({ message: "Some error occurred while retrieving registration." });
        } else {
            logger.info("Successfully retrieved the registration details." + registrationdetails)
            res.send(registrationdetails);
        }
    });
```

};

Above is the code snippet where we are doing find by requester_manager_id in mongoDB if we want to do that same thing in DynamoDB where as requester_manager_id is not Primary Key How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the column is not a primary key of the table, it can be a primary key for the ["Global Secondary Index"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) defined on the table. Then, you can query the index with the filter on Hash Primary Key.

If you cannot / do not want to define a Global Secondary Index, then the other way, which is not recommended, is to scan the table with the filter on this field.

Comment: even with Global secondary Index it asks us to provide primary key of base table  along with  primary key we have created while creating global secondary index.

Comment: The hash primary key of a GSI need not be the same as that of the table. It need not be carrying unique values too. But you can use the hash key of the table as hash key in GSI.